# ajax call works when page loads but will show cors issues with onchange event

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I have this code and it works as expected when page loads, but when I'm trying to make that call after checking checkbox it will show Request header field x-csrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https:/www.bb.com?uId=123&mId=123",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic dTHIgdfgsjdhgfsgfjhsfghsfkjs879"); },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });


and for checking:

$("input:checkbox[name=list]").click(function () {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
do that call
}
});
```

any Idea how to sole that?

Comment: Change `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to allow it … or don't send the token (which the code you've shared **isn't** setting)

Comment: I have no control over server code

Answer (score 0):

ok, so that was fixed by a backend code release. Thanks all for help